# Duplicates in repeater, track-by not helping

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using `ng-repeat`to output the string in an array.

The array looks like so:

```
    "whatToDo": [
        "Many people with Learning Disabilities aren’t aware of their rights. It could be helpful for them to know more about their human rights.",
        "Involve relevant services that may be able to provide support to the person, for example their Community Learning Disability Nurse or Social worker."
    ]
```

When I output the array like so:

```
<p ng-repeat="todos in data.whatToDo">{{todos}}</p>
```

I get the error:

```
Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: todos in data.whatToDo, Duplicate key: string:v, Duplicate value: v
```

When i use the recommended solution of:

```
<p ng-repeat="todos in data.whatToDo track by $index">{{todos}}</p>
```

It only prints out the first letter of each array item.

I have multiple instances of the `whatToDo` array.

Thanks

Comment: there is something missing here.  This works perfectly fine, with or without the `track by`.  http://plnkr.co/edit/LKs6o8qDrRsWTEFVXNxx?p=preview/.  Please show the full object that holds this array.

Comment: can you share controller/link function code ?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle/plunkr that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a working example on how to loop through an array and an array of objects: http://jsfiddle.net/usxmtjnh/3/

copy of this code is below..see if this helps: 

html:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Cntrl">
      <h3>if you have an array:</h3>
      <p ng-repeat="text in whatToDo">{{text}}</p>

      <br><hr>

      <h3>if you have an array of objects:</h3>
      <p ng-repeat="otext in whatToDoObjectCollection">{{otext.line}}</p>
</div>
```

js:

```
angular.module("app", []).controller("Cntrl", function ($scope){

    //array
    $scope.whatToDo = [
    "Many people with Learning Disabilities aren't aware of their rights. It could be helpful for them to know more about their human rights.",
    "Involve relevant services that may be able to provide support to the person, for example their Community Learning Disability Nurse or Social worker."
    ];

    //array of objects
    $scope.whatToDoObjectCollection = [
        {line: "Many people with Learning Disabilities aren't aware of their rights. It could be helpful for them to know more about their human rights."},
        {line: "Involve relevant services that may be able to provide support to the person, for example their Community Learning Disability Nurse or Social worker."}
    ];
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it was the `whatToDoObjectCollection ` style I needed to use

Comment: glad i could help Alan. GL with your app